# How can I simulate this vhdl using modelsim?

Tags: vhdl, simulation, modelsim

I'm new to model sim.
I have this vhdl

-- Code your design here

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity my_and is
port(x : in std_logic; y : in std_logic; z : out std_logic);
end entity my_and;

architecture rtl of my_and is
begin
    z <= x and y;
end architecture rtl;
```

And this test bench

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity my_tb is
end entity my_tb;

architecture rtl of my_tb is
    component my_and is
    port(x : in std_logic; y : in std_logic; z : out std_logic);
    end component my_and;

    signal clk : std_logic := '0';
    signal x : std_logic;
    signal y : std_logic;
    signal z : std_logic;
    constant period : time := 1 ns;
begin

    unit : my_and
        port map(x => x, y => y, z => z);

    clk_process : process
    begin
        clk <= '1';
        wait for period/2;
        clk <= '0';
        wait for period/2;
    end process clk_process;

    unit_proc : process(clk)
        variable count : integer := 0;
    begin
        if(clk'event and clk = '1') then
            if(count mod 4 = 0) then
                x <= '0';
                y <= '0';
            elsif(count mod 4 = 1) then
                x <= '1';
                y <= '0';
            elsif(count mod 4 = 2) then
                x <= '0';
                y <= '1';
            else
                x <= '1';
                y <= '1';
            end if;
        end if;
    count := count + 1;
    end process unit_proc;

end architecture rtl;
```

I've written the test bench by my self, I haven't used the tool. However when I do "Simulation -> Run simulation" the console tell me

> Error loading design

I've set the test bench as top entity. Is there something I could check in order to run the simulation?

In terms of what the console spit out, here's what I get:

```
Compile of my_and.vhd was successful.
# Compile of my_and_tb.vhd was successful.
# 2 compiles, 0 failed with no errors.
vsim -gui work.my_and(rtl)
# vsim 
# Start time: 11:30:05 on Jul 28,2016
# Error loading design
```

Comment: There should have been more errors before the `Error loading design`. Have a look in the log and messages windows.

Comment: The architecture name in `end architecture arch;` doesn't match the declared architecture name (rtl). Process unit_proc is missing a sensitivity list (clk). There's nothing that increments count. And there's nothing that sets the simulation duration (other than the implementation, e.g. run 10 ns). And count mod 2 = 2 is never true. Which also points out you should simply use values of count. Or you could use mod 4.  You should insure count doesn't overflow. After fixing all that I get [waveforms](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4NkQn.png). Check those errors like scary_jeff suggests.

Comment: I fixed all you said, sorry for the silly mistakes. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to simulate the gate,`my_and` not the testbench `my_tb`..

Comment: Shouldn't my "my_tb.." be the top entity?

Comment: Show how you're simulating (what you select) and the error or failure indication you get.

Comment: The problem is the licence expired probably, how can I get a new one (student edition)?

Answer (score -1):

If you have the student edition, make sure you have the license, and if you have the license, make sure youve copied it to the right folder